# Running ISO Without Burning to DVD

Tags: mount, dvd, iso-image

I'm thinking about trying VS 2010, and I plan to download it [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06a32b1c-80e9-41df-ba0c-79d56cb823f7&displaylang=en). However, it's in the form of an ISO file.

Is there anyway to run an ISO image file without burning it to DVD or using a DVD emulator?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/) is free (as in *freedom*, that's better than *free beer*) open-source application that supports all Windows versions since XP.

Comment: +1 - it's like all the other suggestions but without the bloat.  Very specific purpose and does it well.

Answer (score 8):

You can use an ISO mounting software like [Virtual CloneDrive](http://www.slysoft.com/en/virtual-clonedrive.html). It's freeware and very easy to use.

Comment: Unlike Daemon Tools, it runs without problems on Windows 7 x86 and x64.

Comment: Excellent tool, use it all the time on different OS and never hand any problems

Comment: Daemon Tools now runs on x64.

Comment: new link https://www.redfox.bz/en/virtual-clonedrive.html

Answer (score 2):

If by DVD emulator you mean virtual drives, like Daemon Tools, Power ISO or Alcohol %120, I don't know, I always use Daemon Tools.

Comment: Daemon Tools are the best, just remember to uncheck all adware offers when installing.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, you could also use some archiving utility like 7-zip to extract files in iso to a directory. You could probably run install from there. Still, I prefer to use Daemon Tools.

Answer (score 1):

**Windows 8 and up can mount ISO files directly**, no need for any 3<sup>rd</sup> party software. Just double click the ISO file and you're good to go

For older versions there are many free virtual CD software available that you can find on [Freeware ISO mount software](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/7211/3579).

Or you can simply **extract the ISO to a folder** with WinRar, 7z... and run

Answer (score -1):

In most cases, mounting software is unnecessary.
All you need is WinRAR.

I used this tutorial (http://www.pcparrot.net/guides/install-iso-files-without-cd-usb/) to install Windows 8, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Could you please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/745717/edit) your answer to include the relevant details from the tutorial you linked to? Doing this makes sure your answer will remain helpful, even if the link breaks in the future. Thanks!